# Endomorphisms and K-Vector spaces

Tags: group-isomorphism, group-homomorphism

I want to proof (i) and (ii)

(i) Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional K-Vector Space and $f\in End(V)=Hom(V,V)$. If there is a $g\in End(V)$ with $f\circ g=Id_V$, then $f$ is an Isomorphism with $g=f^{-1}$

(ii) Statement (i) is not true for an infinite-dimensional K-Vectorspace $V=Abb(\mathbb{N},K)$ with $Abb(\mathbb{N},K):=\{f|f:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow K\}$.

My ideas:
(i) Let's assume that $\exists g \in End(V): f\circ g=Id_V$. If $f\circ g=Id_V$ then $g\circ f=Id_V$ because $f: V\rightarrow V$. So $g$ is the inverse function of $f$ and $f$ is an automorphism, as it is an isomorphism and an endomorphism.

I am not entirely sure about this proof.

(ii) Here I need help, I know that if $K=\mathbb{R}$ then there cannot be a surjective function $f$ but what if $K=\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: Consider the map $(a_0, a_1, a_2, \dots ) \mapsto (a_1, a_2, \dots)$ (i.e. a shift to the left). What could be the right inverse?

Comment: For (i) use the [Rank–nullity theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem) and the fact that having a right inverse implies surjectivity.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think that your proof for (i) is complete:

First observe that $f \circ g = id_V$ implies that $f$ is surjective: Indeed, any $v \in V$ lies in the image of $f$ as $v = f(w)$ for $w := f(v) \in V$. (Similarly, one can deduce from $f \circ g = id_V$ that $g$ is injective, but this fact is not necessary to prove (i).)

However, it is well-known that surjective $K$-linear maps between finite dimensional vector spaces are necessarily bijective, hence isomorphisms. (Actually, this is not true for infinite dimensional vector spaces, and your task in (ii) is to provide a counterexample.) As a consequence, there exists a $K$-linear map $f^{-1} \colon V \to V$ such that $f \circ f^{-1} = f^{-1} \circ f = id_V$. But from this, we may easily conclude that
$$f^{-1} = f^{-1} \circ id_V = f^{-1} \circ (f \circ g) = (f^{-1} \circ f) \circ g = id_V \circ g = g,$$
proving that $g$ is the inverse of $f$, completing the proof of (i).

Concerning (ii), you may consider the example provided by Severin Schranven in his comment, i.e., the *left shift* $(a_0,a_1,a_2,...) \mapsto (a_1,a_2,...)$. Note here that one may regard any function $f \colon \mathbb{N} = \{0,1,2,3,...\} \to K$ as a sequence $(f(0),f(1),f(2),f(3),...)$.
If the left shift was an isomorphism, then it would in particular be (surjective and) injective. Can you see why the left shift fails to be injective?
And concerning the map $g$, you may think about how one could define a *right shift*.

P.S.: Note that it is impossible to choose $K = \mathbb{N}$, because (when speaking about $K$-vector spaces) $K$ is always assumed to be a field.

Comment: So if we say that every a_n on the left is projected to an a_n on the right, then one a_n is left out, which is why it cannot be injective.

Comment: @calculatormathematical: Yes, this is essentially the reason. For example, both sequences (0,0,0,0,...) and (1,0,0,0,...) are mapped to (0,0,0,0,....) by applying the left shift. (Of course, it then remains to check that the left shift is indeed a linear map.)